# Trying to update table but i always get ora-01427

Tags: oracle, sql-update, subquery, oracle-sqldeveloper

So i am trying to update my Vorschlagspakete table with some values i got from other tables. Precisely there are 3 values i want to write into the main table. Atm it looks like this:

```
update vorschlagspakete
set (paketid, verkaufsstelleid) = (
  select k.paketid, k.verkaufsstelleid
  from Konfiguration k, bewertung b
  where k.konfigurationsid = b.konfigurationsid
  group by k.paketid, k.verkaufsstelleid
  having avg(b.sterne) >= 5);
```

But every time i tried this it results into ora-01427.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error you got, ORA-01427, means **too many rows** (were returned by subquery). For example based on Scott's schema (as I don't have your tables), it looks like this:

```
SQL> update emp e set
  2    (e.ename, e.job) = (select d.dname, d.loc from dept d);
  (e.ename, e.job) = (select d.dname, d.loc from dept d)
                      *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
```

Why wouldn't it work? Because subquery returns more than a single row!

```
SQL> select d.dname, d.loc from dept d;

DNAME          LOC
-------------- -------------
ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
RESEARCH       DALLAS
SALES          CHICAGO
OPERATIONS     BOSTON

SQL>
```

So, how would you put all those values into a single row of the EMP table? That won't work, obviously, so you have to *do something* to restrict number of rows. How? Well, it depends.

- sometimes `DISTINCT` helps, e.g.

  ```
  select distinct d.dname, d.loc from dept d
  ```
- sometimes additional `WHERE` condition helps, e.g.

  ```
  select d.dname, d.loc from dept d
  where d.location = 'NEW YORK'
  ```
- sometimes joining with the table to be updated helps, e.g.

  ```
  select d.dname, d.loc from dept d where d.deptno = e.deptno
  ```

  which leads to

  ```
  SQL> update emp e set
    2    (e.ename, e.job) = (select d.dname, d.loc from dept d where d.deptno =       e.deptno);

  14 rows updated.
  ```

What should you do? I don't know, we don't have your data. See whether something written above helps.